Extract oldest entry from JSON
I'm trying to get a curl response and be able to call it like an object. I've been googling for a while and have seen a lot of answers around jq. I've been trying to make that work but I can't seem to find the exact syntax. My ideal solution is that I grab all the uploaded_at values, then sort, then determine which is the oldest.
This is my curl command:
url="https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps"
curl -u "xxx:xxx" -X GET "$url"

It returns something like:
[{"app_name":"FlyreelSample.ipa","app_version":"1.1.0","app_url":"bs://76867867","app_id":"76867867","uploaded_at":"2024-08-21 14:41:53 UTC"},
 {"app_name":"FlyreelSample.ipa","app_version":"1.1.0","app_url":"bs://8567463","app_id":"8567463","uploaded_at":"2024-08-21 14:40:29 UTC"},
 {"app_name":"app-stage-debug.apk","app_version":"1.0","app_url":"bs://834534534","app_id":"834534534","uploaded_at":"2024-08-12 15:00:34 UTC"}
]

I've tried the following command:
curl -u "xxxx:xxxxx" -X GET "$url" | jq -r '.uploaded_at'

And I get the following error:
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "uploaded_at"
I also tried some sed and Awk solutions. Also tried putting it to a file but also didn't work. It never put the values into the file
curl -u "xxxx:xxxxx" -X GET "$url" -d @test.txt


Your sample shows an array with two objects. Both contain an uploaded_at key. Which one do you want to extract? Use … | jq -r '.[0].uploaded_at' for the first one, … | jq -r '.[1].uploaded_at' for the second one, or … | jq -r '.[].uploaded_at' for all of them.

Ah gotcha. So I technically want all of them so I can sort and decide which is older

Sort before you extract. E.g. … | jq -r 'sort_by(.uploaded_at)[].app_name'

Awesome!!! Thank you so much. Can I also add a group by? Basically I know want a list of similar items. So all .IPA and all .APK
So I want the oldest .IPA and the oldest .APK

jq is the right tool for this;  awk isn't going to help much with Json.  The problem @awhistler, is that the json top level is a list / array [].  Try jq  '.[]|.uploaded_at'

Sure, try … | jq 'group_by(.app_name | .[rindex("."):])' or … | jq 'group_by(.app_name / "." | last)'. This groups by whatever comes after the last dot in app_name.

One more thing @pmf so I want to group by and sort but then I want to grab the value of the first item (aka the older) so I can get the app_id and I can't seem to figure out how. I did SORTED=$(curl -u "xxx:xxxx" \ -X GET "api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq 'group_by(.app_name / "." | first)' | jq -r 'sort_by(.[0].uploaded_at)[] | reverse'). This gives me the two arrays but then from each array, I want to grab the app_id that has the older date (which should always be index 0 now) and every time I try to do that, it basically ignores my sort I just did

@awhisler Without sample data, it's hard to follow what you're after. Generally speaking: Don't concatenate calls to jq, write up a single filter. Sorting on a single item doesn't make sense. But if your only reason to sort was to get the first or last item, use min_by or max_by instead. Also, you've changed last to first in group_by, so it'll match on what comes before the dot, not after it. All that said, try out group_by(.app_name / "." | last)[] | min_by(.uploaded_at).app_id (and play around using this demo).

Totally fair. That does get me 1 step closer but I realized after I saw that I only it to return the app_id if there is more than one item in the array so I think I need two separate calls.
First: SORTED=$(curl -u "xxx:xxxx" \ -X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps" | jq 'group_by(.app_name / "." | last)' | jq -r 'sort_by(.[0].uploaded_at)[] | reverse') - this gives me the two arrays. THEN I want to say, if either of those arrays has more than one obj, then give me the app_id. If there is only 1 in the array of Android or iOS, then dont give me anything

Re "The sample data is in the original post": Your sample is an array of two objects, which is not suitable to be grouped, sorted, filtered, and then have its items counted reasonably. By starting with only two items, you either partition into groups of at most one item, which renders sorting and counting them meaningless, or you go with a single group containing both items while losing any distinctive attributes towards other (empty) groups. Instead, construct (make up) a minimal sample containing all the edge cases but excluding unnecessary details, and post your desired exact result from it

Oh my bad. Let me update it to 3 items.

One more item won't fix my issues. Re "I think I need two separate calls": Very unlikely. Re "if either of those arrays has more than one obj, then give me the app_id": So, in that case you want a single app_id, namely the one from the object with the earliest uploaded_at? Re "If there is only 1 in the array of Android or iOS, then dont give me anything": I don't know what "the array of Android or iOS" is but you can simply select (i.e. keep) an array based on its length. My updated guess: … | jq -r 'group_by(.app_name / "." | last)[] | select(length > 1) | min_by(.uploaded_at).app_id'

I know there are a lot of comments with great snippets but wanted to answer the question for other readers' convenience.
The question required to grab all the uploaded_at values, then sort, then determine which is the oldest
To get the oldest date:
curl -s https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps | jq -r 'sort_by(.uploaded_at)[0].uploaded_at'

To get the relevant object of the oldest uploaded_at:
curl -s https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/recent_apps | jq -r 'sort_by(.uploaded_at)[0]'

